# Proving a function is constant, if a sum of the real and imaginary parts is bounded

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $g$ be an entire function such that there exist three
>   real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ such that $a$ and $b$ are not both $0$ and such that
>   $$a \operatorname{Re}(g(z)) + b \operatorname{Im}(g(z)) ≤ c$$
>   for all $ z ∈ \mathbb{C}$.
>
> Show that $g$ is constant.

Solving simpler versions of this problem involves defining a new function, say $h(z)$, that is some (often exponential) function we can find to be bounded. What do we do in our case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h(z)=(a-bi)g(z)$. Then$$(\forall z\in\mathbb{C}):\operatorname{Re}h(z)\leqslant c.$$Now, define $f(z)=e^{h(z)}$. Then$$(\forall z\in\mathbb{C}):\bigl\lvert f(z)\bigr\rvert=e^{\operatorname{Re}h(z)}\leqslant e^c.$$Can you take it from here?